# How to change label background color dynamically?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

For instance, there is a label (without textfield!):

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Label', {
   id: "lb1",
   height: 20,
   html: "Title"
   cls: 'cls1'
})
```

How can I change the background color dynamically without a CSS?

Comment: why don't you want to use CSS?

Comment: The background color is used as classication property. For instance from dark red for very bad to light green for very good. So it is uncomfortable to generate so many CSS styles.

Comment: keeping styles in a separate css files is better approach in most cases, but for your case 2nd case in my answer is the option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of ways to achieve that, but all of them use manipulate CSS.

*1. Change css class on label*

**CSS classes**

> ```
> .cls1 {
>     background-color: #fff;
> }
>
> .cls2 {
>     background-color: #ccc;
> }
> ```

**ExtJS**

```
label.removeCls('cls1');
label.addCls('cls2');
```

*2. Change style on DOM Element*

> label.getEl().setStyle('background', '#CCC');

Good Luck!